# Write to same file in pytest multiprocessing

Tags: python, pytest, multiprocess, pytest-xdist

There is a pytest test suite that gets run in multiprocess/parallel via `pytest-xdist`. Some of these tests write to the same file, which can become problematic when multiprocessing.

I thought that doing something like this would do the trick, but hasn't been successful:

In `util.py`:

```
import multiprocessing

LOCK = multiprocessing.Lock()
```

And in `test_something.py`:

```
from util import LOCK
...
def test_something():
    ...
    LOCK.acquire()
    write_to_file()
    LOCK.release()
    ...
```

Sometimes the tests would hang, or sometimes there would be a WRITE/READ issue.

Am I placing the `LOCK` at an incorrect location? Is there a way to pass a global object across all of the tests? Or am I thinking about it the wrong way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pytest-xdist` but you need to make sure that the lock is actually shared with all the processes, i.e. that (on Linux/MacOS) all child processes get forked from the original process in which you created the lock or that you pass the lock to those child processes explicitly via `multiprocessing.Process(target, args=(LOCK, ))`. So the question is: How does `pytest-xdist` create the processes and can you somehow adjust the way this is done?

Answer (score 1):

For that, you'll probably want to use https://py-filelock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

`pip install filelock`, then try the examples, eg:

```py
from filelock import Timeout, FileLock

lock = FileLock("high_ground.txt.lock")
with lock:
    open("high_ground.txt", "a").write("You were the chosen one.")
```